# Converting Windows Hyperlinks to Work on a Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have created a Excel 2016 spreadsheet in Windows on a thumb drive with hundreds of hyperlinks.  The hyperlinks pathed to subfolders on the thumbdrive were created through VBA and function flawlessly on a Windows computer.  When the thumb drive is moved to a different computer I have written additional VBA which detects the path based on the drive letter and updates both the hyperlink and the text folder path.  I am limited, however, to Windows as a Mac does not use drive letters.

I have been searching various forums and general Googling for a how-to for converting the spreadsheet's hyperlinks to Mac functionality.  I have found little to assist.  Most reference notes seem to indicate that a hyperlink must be created on the Mac, that once created the hyperlink is "bound" to that Mac, and that it is otherwise not possible to use the Windows-created Excel 2016 spreadsheet hyperlinks on a Mac.

Assumptions made would be that the Mac is using Bootcamp, Parallels, VMWare Fusion or other Windows emulator that would (a) enable use of an Excel 2016 spreadsheet in Office for Mac; and that (b) the Mac is capable of opening the hyperlinked file by having the needed application installed, i.e., .pdf, .doc/.docx, .xls/xlsx, .ppt/.pptx, .mpeg, .mpg2, .mpg3, .mp4, etc.  I understand that it might be complicated if the file was, e.g, a .wma or .wmv which could open on a Mac through, e.g., VLC Media Player, but mostly doesn't.

I am in the legal field, and the capability to batch-create the hyperlinks in Windows to a sharable thumb drive re-pathed to a Mac would help . . . even though a Mac is not generally "friendly or widely used in the Judiciary except for basic Office-application documents (primarily Word, Excel and PowerPoint).

If anyone has run across this problem, any insights would be appreciated.  If possible I am seeking to better understand the non-drive letter Mac envirnonment and VBA which would batch re-write the Windows hyperlink to conform to Mac usability.

Comment: It is usually in the format `='ExternalDriveName:FolderNameIfAny:[MyFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1` It doesn't have the concept of C: or D:. It is "name" of the drive.

Comment: In MAC when you insert the thumb drive, it's name will reflect on the desktop. You may want to keep it simple? Say something like `MyThumDrive` and then you can use say `='MyThumDrive:[MyFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1`. If the file is in a folder then use the format as shown above. One more important thing. Your VBA Win Code may have to be (not necessarily though) re-written so that it runs on MAC.

Comment: COMMENT - Part A . . . Siddharth ... I was going to supplement with the question whether naming the drive, e.g., SMITH, would assist.  It does, so thank you. == I understand VBA will likely not run on a Mac, so my plan was to create the hyperlinks in Windows with VBA, and then use VBA to update the hyperlink path to the Mac format so that when the Excel Spreadsheet is opened on the Mac that clicking the hyperlink would find the file and launch/open/play it.

Comment: COMMENT - Part B . . . Assuming my Windows path structure was E:\Case\House\Kitchen\Counter\Sink.jpg, I am trying to see what the updated hyperlink would be.  Am I seeing it correctly as ='Smith:Case:House:Kitchen:Counter:[Sink.jpg]Sheet1'!A.  The hyperlinks would all be on Sheet 1, but I don't understand the "!A" and its purpose, or is that a Mac requirement.  Also, are the [brackets] included or is that just indicated for the location of the file to be opened?  Thank you for your assistance.  I think I am getting it, but it is a Mac and they have their own issues.

Comment: `!A1` It was just an example. A1 is the addess of a cell in a worksheet. `Am I seeing it correctly as ='Smith:Case:House:Kitchen:Counter:[Sink.jpg]`. No. If it is a link to a file and not to a cell address then it would look something like this `file//localhost/Volumes/SMITH/Case/House/Kitchen/Counter/Sink.Jpg`. To test this. Open a new excel. Click on `Insert|Hyperlink` and then select the image(under document)

Comment: So in short... `D:\Case\House\Kitchen\Counter\Sink.Jpg` in windows becomes `file//localhost/Volumes/SMITH/Case/House/Kitchen/Counter/Sink.Jpg` in MAC. Windows doesn't use the name (SMITH) of the drive. Also the backslash "\" becomes the forward slash "/"

Comment: Siddharth . . . I believe this give me enough to work with.  My spreadsheet configuration is: ColA (FriendlyNameDescription) - ColB [Hyperlink] - ColC (Notes).  All of the hyperlinks would be B1:B500.  This really helps.  Thank you, sir.